# How do I compare two columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a two table both with a SSN variable, and I want to show the ones that are in only one table, not both.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: sql ...and I need so many characters

Comment: That's not an answer. SQL is generic, we need to know which DBMS: MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, TSQL.

Comment: I'm sorry that was really dumb of me MYSQL is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select coalesce(t1.ssn, t2.ssn)
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t1.ssn = t2.ssn
where t1.ssn is null or t2.ssn is null;
```

This works in most databases, but not in MySQL.  The following should work in pretty much any database:

```
select ssn
from ((select ssn, 't1' as which
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select ssn, 't2' as which
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by ssn
having count(distinct which) = 1
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in mysql, it doesn't have `full outer join`.

Comment: @Barmar . . . `full outer join` is standard SQL and the question does not indicate the database.

Comment: I know, it was just a point of information. I usually wait for the OP to answer the question of which DB.